# One line if statement in bash

Tags: bash, if-statement

I've never programed in bash... yet I'm trying to solve a problem for an anchievement in a game (codingame.com)

I have the following code:

```
for (( i=0; i<N-1; i++ )); do
   tmp=$(( sorted_array[i+1] - sorted_array[i] ));
   if [ $tmp < $result ]; then result=$tmp fi
done
```

And this error:

```
/tmp/Answer.sh: line 42: syntax error near unexpected token `done'at Answer.sh. on line 42
/tmp/Answer.sh: line 42: `done' at Answer.sh. on line 42
```

I want to compare adjacent values of my array and store the minimun diference between them... but I cant figure how to do an If statement in bash

Comment: Running this through http://shellcheck.net/ would catch some items which, for that matter, folks here haven't.

Comment: Mind you -- `if (( tmp < result )); then result=$tmp; fi` is also an option, which gets rid of the `-lt` vs `<` issue, *and* the potential for quoting.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Each command must be properly terminated, either by a newline or a semi-colon.  In this case, you need to separate the assignment of `result` from the keyword `fi`.  Try adding a semi-colon;

```
for (( i=0; i<N-1; i++ )); do
   tmp=$(( sorted_array[i+1] - sorted_array[i] ))
   if [ "$tmp" -lt "$result" ]; then result=$tmp; fi
done
```

Also, you need to use `lt` rather than `<`, since `<` is a redirection operator.  (Unless you intend to run a command named `$tmp` with input from a file named by the variable `$result`)

Comment: The commands needs to be *separated* by semi-colons, not terminated by them.

Comment: separating the tokens serves to terminate the command in the parser.

Comment: The semicolon indicates the end of a statement, it doesn't terminate anything.

Comment: Fine, it terminates a statement then, are you arguing with yourself now ??

Comment: @ikegami Stop to be a pedantic fool here! Fix your own answer since it is actually wrong.

Comment: "separating" is probably clearer, and "separating the tokens" makes perfect sense, but is not quite accurate.  The `$tmp` token is already separated from the `fi` token.

Comment: You just said it doesn't need to be terminated by the semi colons, then corrected me saying it does ? MAke up your mind.

Comment: But, no, "separating the commands" makes no sense, because `fi` is not a command but a keyword.  The problem is that without the semi-colon, the command shell is parsing the command as the sequence `result=$tmp fi`, so it tries to run a command `fi` with `result` set in its environment, because the assignment operator as a stand alone command was not properly terminated with a semi-colon.

Comment: Still says you need to terminate the commands, but it's not true. You can remove the `;` from the OP's second line

Comment: @ikegami Yes, you can omit the semi-colon, but the command is still terminated by the newline.  I agree with you that 'terminate the commands' is potentially misleading, but it is correct.

Comment: Needs more quotes. If `result` is empty (or has a non-numeric value) on the first pass, it can split into a number of words other than one. And if IFS contains digits, even worse...

Comment: After `then` no semicolon, otherwise you get error.

Answer (score 10):

You are missing a semicolon and need to use `-lt` instead of `<`, as others pointed out.

An alternative to the `if` statement would be to use the logical *and* operator `&&`:

```
for (( i=0; i<N-1; i++ )); do
   tmp=$(( sorted_array[i+1] - sorted_array[i] ))
   [ $tmp -lt $result ] && result=$tmp
done
```

Comment: @User112638726 You think if somebody ask *"How do I jump out of the window"* I'm not allowed to answer *"Please don't do it!"*? Is does explicitely say: `Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative.`. Please read the FAQ before you down-vote and/or comment posts.

Comment: @User112638726 Link to the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer .. You actually did vandalizm, I've flagged that.

Comment: Poor analogy, they're not doing anything dangerous. You've just posted an identical answer to the accepted one with a a pointless addition of &&, which does nothing but hurt readability.

Comment: So you think a `test && cmd` is not a viable alternative for a single command, one-line if statement in bash? Common! Discussion ended.

Answer (score -1):

Your `if` needs to be followed by a `fi` command, but you don't have any such command. You have a `fi` in your code, but it's in the middle of another command, so it no more completes the `if` then the `fi` in `echo fi` would. If you're going to merge lines together, you need to use a semi-colon to separate the commands.

So to collapse

```
for (( i=0; i<N-1; i++ ))
do
   tmp=$(( sorted_array[i+1] - sorted_array[i] ))
   if [ $tmp -lt $result ]
   then 
      result=$tmp
   fi
done
```

you'd use

```
for (( i=0; i<N-1; i++ )); do
   tmp=$(( sorted_array[i+1] - sorted_array[i] ))
   if [ $tmp -lt $result ]; then result=$tmp; fi
done
```

- Exception: `do` and `then` can be followed by a command, so you don't need a semi-colon after them when you merge in the next line.
- Notice how you don't need to terminate your commands with `;`? `;` is only needed between commands.
- Inside of a `test` (`[]`), `-lt` is used to compare numbers.

Comment: You may want to use the arithmetic operator for the comparison `-lt`